# How do I get list of all filenames in a directory using VB6?

Tags: vb6, file, directory

What is the simplest way in VB6 to loop through all the files in a specified folder directory and get their names?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
sFilename = Dir(sFoldername)

Do While sFilename > ""

  debug.print sFilename 
  sFilename = Dir()

Loop
```

Comment: Damn, beat me to it :P
Have an MSDN article for reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262726(VS.60).aspx

Answer (score 12):

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fld As Folder
Dim fil As File
Set fld = fso.GetFolder("C:\My Folder")
For Each fil In fld.Files
  Debug.Print fil.Name
Next
Set fil = Nothing
Set fld = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Answer (score 5):

DJ's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291849/how-do-i-get-list-of-all-filenames-in-a-directory-using-vb6#291882) is simple and effective, just throwing out another one in case you need a little more functionality that the FileSystemObject can provide (requires a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime).

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fil As File

For Each fil In fso.GetFolder("C:\").Files
  Debug.Print fil.Name
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

'For VB6 very Tricky:
'Simply get the location of all project .frm files saved in your disk/project directory

Dim CountVal As Integer
CountVal = 0
cbo.Clear

```
sFilename = Dir(App.Path & "\Forms\")
Do While sFilename > ""
  If (Right(sFilename, 4) = ".frm") Then
  cbo.List(CountVal) = Left(sFilename, (Len(sFilename) - 4))
  CountVal = CountVal + 1
  End If

   sFilename = Dir()
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

create button with name = browseButton
create filelistbox with name = List1

double click on button in design

and code should look like this

```
Private Sub browseButton_Click()

Dim path  As String
path = "C:\My Folder"

List1.path() = path
List1.Pattern = "*.txt"
End Sub
```

done now run it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following demo code,

```
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fld As Folder
Dim file As File
Set fld = fso.GetFolder("C:\vishnu")
For Each file In fld.Files
  msgbox file.Name
Next
```